# No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

Tags: spring, persistence

Using Spring Core 3.0.5, Hibernate 3.6.0.
The title of this question is the message of a java.lang.IllegalStateException raised on starting a Tomcat webserver (6.0.29) with an application I am maintaining.

applicationContext.xml says:

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
   <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml is in the META-INF directory of a jar file the project includes. Expedissimo.web.war has a WEB-INF/classes folder with said .jar.

The complete exception traceback on starting the server is:

> GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé
>   (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener)
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence
>   units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from
>   {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.determinePersistenceUnitInfo(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)

```
... 36 more
```

persistence.xml says:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="serv2010pool" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> 
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.autocommit" value="false" /> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"     value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.insee.poolName" value="serv2010pool" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value=
            "fr.insee.config.hibernate.InseeConnectionProvider"/>           
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The same persistence unit descriptor, when used outside Spring in the batch sibling project, is found and parsed correctly from

```
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("serv2010pool");
```

The batch project, just like the web project, includes Serv2010-1.0.jar, which has META-INF/persistence.xml . All annotated classes are in this common jar.

Deploying inside Eclipse v3.6 raises the exception. The WEB-INF/classes/ folder in the .war doesn't have the persistence.xml file. Adding it manually and restarting the server doesn't help.

Any idea? I'm running out of tricks here, thanks for providing any.
CChris

Answer (score 10):

This usually means that Spring can't find `persistence.xml`.

Make sure that `persistence.xml` is in `META-INF` in relation to your classpath.

This might mean you have to put the file in `WEB-INF\classes\META-INF`, even though it seems strange.

Comment: If the META-INF folder doesn't exist, just create it and place the persistance.xml file inside

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Maven the META-INF folder should be placed within `src/main/resources`, once the file be there the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Are you config packagesToScan property in entityManagerFactory bean?

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem.But issue was resolved after adding "packagesToScan" property in entityFactoryManagerBean definition in spring.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to the other answers:

I had the same problem and was also using maven.  I had to do a fresh clean before the error dissipated. Might be obvious to some but someone else might find this useful. :)