# Spring JPA java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am facing below issue with Spring JPA. I have done java configuration with NO xml.

I am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}"

Below is my application config class.

```
package co.in.desertlamp.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "co.in.desertlamp")
@ComponentScan({ "co.in.desertlamp" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/co/in/desertlamp/resources/desertlamp.properties" })
public class DesertLampApplicationConfig {

    private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_FORMATSQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "co.in.desertlamp" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(DataSourceCondition.class)
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        //Put Logger here
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/co/in/desertlamp/scripts/loadUserAndRoleData.sql"));
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL));
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_FORMATSQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMATSQL));
        hibernateProperties.put(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL));
        return hibernateProperties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
       HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
       return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No persistence units parsed from {classpath\*:META-INF/persistence.xml}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651919/no-persistence-units-parsed-from-classpathmeta-inf-persistence-xml)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` needs to know the location of your `@Entity` classes.

So adding below properties should fix it:

```
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("path.to.your.entities");
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("name");
```

Comment: Doesn't it mean we still need to define the persistenceUnit in persistence.xml?

Comment: There is no persistence.xml in case of the question being asked, all java config. Cheers.